# How to read positions from tf::TransformBroadcaster

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may be a bit of a dumb question, but how do you read poses from tf::TransformBroadcaster?

The wiki, http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29, explains how to send poses using it, but now how to read poses (if that is something you do).

If you are not supposed to read poses from tf::TransformBroadcaster, then what exactly is the purpose of it?

When i say "read" from a tf::TransformBroadcaster, i mean to define a callback for a topic like normal

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234308/how-to-read-positions-from-tf::transformbroadcaster/) by [erwhelewoli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26166/erwhelewoli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do not read from a Broadcaster as it is (as the name suggest) only broadcasting transformations. You can use a Listener to get transformations: http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28Python%29

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0